# How to calculate with date ranges

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Ok this coding piece - the TAT - may be simple for you but I am beating my head over this.

This returns the # of toys for each girl

```
Select Toys,
Count(Girls),
TAT
from Table1 (nolock)
```

i.e.

```
Girl       Toys           TAT
_____      ______         ___________

Kelly       1              0-5
Michelle    1              16-30
Grace       1              31+
Katy        1              6-10
Kelly       1              16-30
```

This returns the # of Toys in each age range

```
Select TAT,
Count(TAT)
from Table1 (nolock)
```

i.e.

```
TAT          ??????
_____        ___________
0-5             1
6-10            0
11-15           1
16-30           2
31+             1
```

The next step I need do is to divide 1 (Kelly for 16-30) by # of Toys in age range it was put in (2 for 16-30) :

```
1  / 2  = 50.00%
```

How do I do that? The column with the ???? is where I am stuck at.

Thank you!
Holly

Comment: UGH - I hope you get this since this is not exactly how I had it laid out....

Comment: Can you give the complete expected resulting table?

Comment: For this - basically show the % of each toy(s) in each date range.

Comment: Don't worry about the posts - just look at the summary....I know it will not be in exact layout but this is just a step closer to what I need....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548261/how-can-i-generate-a-formatted-report-from-a-stored-procedure

Comment: In the summary - this I just need to do the vertical columns...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table #table1 (Girl varchar(20), toys int, tat varchar(10))  
insert into #table1 (Girl, toys, tat)  
 values ('Kelly',1,'0-5')  
,('Michelle',1,'16-30')  
,('Grace',1,'31+')  
,('Katy',1,'6-10')  
,('Kelly',1,'16-30')  

declare @dividend numeric(5,2) = 1  
;with gtcount as (select tat, COUNT(*) ctr  
                  from #table1  
                  group by tat )  
select tat,ctr, @dividend/ctr percentage from gtcount
```

Hope this helps...
Elmer

Comment: Elmer - Will try yours now as well :) And let you know!

Comment: This works as outside of stored procedure. JLo's code works within the stored procedure :)

Answer (score 0):

You sound really confused - out of the goodness of my heart, I took a stab at this. If this is not correct, you need to post more information on what exactly you need.

a. Your example queries are not correct (they will error due to missing `GROUP BY`)

b. Your sample data is incomplete. In the first step, your data seems to indicate you want to group by Girl and TAT, but you explicitly say your query is counting toys per girl - not toys per Girl/TAT pair. Which is right?

"show the % of each toy(s) in each date range". This is not so simple when the sample data is incomplete

```
;WITH GirlTATCount AS (
  SELECT
    Girl,
    TAT,
    COUNT(*) as [ToyCount]
  FROM Table1
  GROUP BY Girl, TAT
)
, ToysInAgeRange AS (
  SELECT
    TAT,
    COUNT(*) as [ToyCount]
  FROM Table1
  GROUP BY TAT
)
SELECT
  gtc.Girl,
  gtc.TAT,
  gtc.ToyCount,
  CAST(gtc.ToyCount as float) / CAST(tar.ToyCount as float) as [%]
FROM GirlTATCount gtc
JOIN ToysInAgeRange tar
  ON tar.TAT = gtc.TAT
```

Comment: J Lo...I apologize that I left off the group bys. I have had to hardcode a lot of columns for a couple of stored procedures (unrelated to this) at work today...I can't believe I did that. I will definitely try your example code and see how that comes out. And I will let you know. Much appreciation here. And I promise I will explain better after testing this coding.

Comment: J Lo, one question...I have never heard of WITH in SQL, can you kindly explain to me what it does and so on? Thank you so much again.

Comment: It's called a Common Table Expression. [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Quick question: How do you convert the % to 50.00% instead of .5? Thank you!

Comment: Actually I figured  it out :) Convert(decimal(6,2), CAST(gtc.ToyCount as float)*100 / CAST(tar.ToyCount as float)) as [%]